# fadeout effect with hide in jquery

Tags: jquery, fadeout, effect

I am trying to hide a div with a fadeout effect but it doesn't seem to work..

`$('#messageDiv').hide().fadeOut('slow');` Any suggestion.

I am showing an error div using a custom function?

```
function getErrorMsgStyle(txt) {
    return "<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'><tr style='line-height:7px;'><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table><div class='error_Style_Border' id='messageDiv'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick=\"$('#messageDiv').fadeOut('slow');\"  class='link'><table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'><tr style='line-height:2px;'><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='table_error_Style_Border'><table width='97%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center' >" + "<tr style='line-height:2px;'><td colspan='15' align='center'></td></tr>" + "<tr ><td width='10px'>&nbsp;</td><td colspan='12' align='center' ><span class='error-txt'>" + txt + "</span></td><td width='10px' class='error-close'>X</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr>" + "<tr style='line-height:2px;'><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></a></div><a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick=\"$('#messageDiv').fadeOut('slow');\" class='link'><table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'><tr style='line-height:7px'><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></a>";
}
```

Also `$('#messageDiv').fadeOut('slow');` doesn't seem to work

Comment: BTW, what are those <table> tags in the return for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#messageDiv').fadeOut('slow');
```

or

```
$('#messageDiv').fadeOut(250);
```

meaning the fade should take 250 milliseconds.

Ensure also that your element has the name of messageDiv and not something else.

**edit**

You could use a classname instead if the id if you are using webForms and finding that the id is not what you're expecting.  I actually prefer this approach as it's less hit-n-miss

**edit 2**

Change your href to `href='.'` and your click event to `$('#messageDiv').fadeOut('slow');return false;`

Comment: @griegs ya i am using webforms.. But still i cant make it to work

Comment: Change your href to href='.' and your click event to $('#messageDiv').fadeOut('slow');return false;

Comment: @greigs what's the point in making a change to href could u explain

Comment: I've never actually seen the javascript notation you used with void(0) so I removed it. :)

Comment: Jumping effect?  it might just be the broswer, IE i've noticed can do a lot of jumping.  You might also have a lot of elements on the page that the browser is trying to move up as you hide your error.

Comment: btw:  i tried it here and there was no jumping in IE but it was on a page with few elements on it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using this in your error div:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick=\"$('#messageDiv').fadeOut('slow');\"  class='link'>
```

Since you're using jQuery anyway, you might want to rewrite that particular tag by giving it an ID and attaching the onclick event using jQuery live().

Use:

```
<a href='#' id='hide_link' class='link'>
```

and use the following Javascript code somewhere below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#hide_link').live('click',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();    // this will prevent the default link-click action
         $('#messageDiv').fadeOut('slow');
     });
});
```